# newly installed civi - 'Organization address and contact info', page frozen cannot edit

Tags: civicrm-home

I just installed CiviCRM 4.6.31 then also tested 4.7 as well on drupal 7 with inmotionhosting. 
PROBLEM: On my main site admin pages 'civicrm home' 'config checklist'->Organization Address and Contact Info page does nothing, frozen.  This happens on my dev machine and my server for my main site.  On both, I install civicrm.  I get the green light saying everything is ready to install.  I install and immediately find I cannot edit the Org address and contact info.  I get no errors even if I turn on debug etc... I am not really sure where to look for errors.  To test further I then installed fresh drupal 7 and added no content then added civicrm on my dev system and my server. These work correctly... So it is not the systems.  I do not really want to have to rebuild my website...  The testing really should pre tell me if something will conflict.  I spent a lot of time on this and now consider this a bug.  I am willing to go to super levels of cooperation with civi developers should they be interested in why this will not install correctly on a seemingly functional website.

I thought this might have been because it was setup as a multisite but testing proved that incorrect..  I am willing to assist with understanding this.

Comment: I believe your civicrm_settings.php should be located in sites/default.

Comment: sites/domain is possible on a multi-site Drupal install;

Comment: turns out the settings problem was just a different unrelated problem.  That problem was cleared and the main problem persisted.  Also subsequent installs proved the system installed by acquia dev desktop was not the culprit.

Comment: A couple of response on MM https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/3amyzd4bopr4uqd483md9uuaec